# Antlr4 expression with conditional missing separator

Tags: antlr4

I want to parse Smalltalk.
Normally in a sequence of expressions, they need a PERIOD token (.) in between as a separator, like the ';' in java.
An expression alone does not need the PERIOD.
Hence i match this PERIOD in the expressions rule:

`expressions : expression (PERIOD expression)*;`

And the different sub-rules for the specific expression do not match the PERIOD by themselves.

However, there is one special type of expression, that calls to native libraries:
`<primitive: ABC>`

And when this is followed by another expression, the PERIOD is surprisingly **not** needed.

How can such a situation be handled?

Perhaps injecting a PERIOD. From within the "primitive" rule, tell the lexer to inject a PERIOD token next. But how?

Or is there a better solution for this situation?

Frank

Comment: When you say the period is not needed, is it not allowed or is it optional? And can just `<primitive: ABC>` be a complete expression on it's own or must it be followed by an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
expressions
 : start_expression* expression '.'?
 ;

start_expression
 : expression '.'
 | pragma
 ;

expression
 : assignment
 | pragma
 ;

assignment
 : ID ':=' NUMBER
 ;

pragma
 : '<' ID ':' ID '>'
 ;
```

Comment: Oh yes, instead of having the expressions with (first remaining*), have it (start* last). This solves it. Thanks for the lesson.